# Mac Pro late 2013 stucked, can't install mojave

Tags: macos, mac, macos-highsierra, macos-mojave, mac-pro

Yesterday i was working normally on my mac and it got stuck, the display was frozen but the sound was working. I clicked the power button until it turned off and then i wasn't able to boot again.

I reinstalled osx but it installed osx mavericks, and it works fine, but when i try to update to macOS mojave or high sierra it get stuck in installation. I tried to install by direct installation and by bootable usb and it get stuck by both ways.

My question is if you think that is a hardware problem or is something that i am doing wrong? Do i have to install other osx before i install mojave or high sierra?

I already formated the ssd and reset the nvram and pvram and it stills happens.
I don't know what to do more.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You may have better luck cloning an existing macOS drive using https://www.shirt-pocket.com/SuperDuper/SuperDuperDescription.html or Carbon copy cloner.

Its possible the drive went bad so you could also try using the disk from another mac. Restart the broken mac and hold the option key until the available startup drives are listed. Boot the other mac up while holding the "T" key until the target disk mode icon flashes. Connect the two macs via cable and if the broken mac is able to boot -> good news its just a hard drive failure, otherwise it may be the motherboard :(

The last thing to try (or first) is the apple hardware test https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201257

Comment: Thank you Brady Coye, i will try this solutions.

Comment: I don't have another mac to clone, i can test if is the hard drive by installing the osx in the external drive and boot from that drive, right? if it don't work with the external hard drive is the motherboard.

Comment: But it's weird being some hardware problem because when i install osx Mavericks it works fine, at least it seems to work fine.

Comment: With external hard drive it freezes like with internal hard drive. In verbose mode i am able to see where it freezes is in AppleCamIn::start

Comment: UPDATE: memory RAM corrupted, just in case it happens to anyone

Comment: would you vote on my answer, Im new and have no rep lol